How to check if a Django Model Instance contains a foreign key or not
I need to serialize data coming from Django Audit Log Entry in such a way that when in changes field There is a Field present which has a value of foreign key I need to fetch the value of that Foreign key from database and Change the Foreign key with the value.
def get_changes(self, obj):
        changes_data = obj.changes
        if changes_data:
            model_name = obj.content_type.model_class().__name__
            try:
                field_mapping = getattr(ma_activity_tracker, f"{model_name}_display_atrb")
            except AttributeError:
                field_mapping = {}
            
            changes = {}
            
            for field, (old_value, new_value) in changes_data.items():
                field_name = field_mapping.get(field, field)
                field_object = globals().get(model_name)
                
                
                print(field_object.User)
                # if isinstance(field_object, models.ForeignKey):
                if isinstance(field_object,models.ForeignKey):
                    
                    
                    old_related_obj = field_object.related_model.objects.filter(pk=int(old_value)).first()
                    new_related_obj = field_object.related_model.objects.filter(pk=int(new_value)).first()

                   
                    old_display_value = getattr(old_related_obj, field_name) if old_related_obj else None
                    new_display_value = getattr(new_related_obj, field_name) if new_related_obj else None

                    
                    old_value = old_display_value
                    new_value = new_display_value
                    
                
                changes[field_name] = {
                    "Old Value": old_value,
                    "New Value": new_value
                }
        
            return changes
        return None

This is what I tried but to do but the if block never gets executed
